# What is pic_width_in_luma_samples in HEVC?

Tags: hevc

What does pic_width_in_luma_samples mean in H265 format?

User manual say
pic_width_in_luma_samples specifies the width of each decoded picture in units of luma samples.
pic_width_in_luma_samples shall not be equal to 0 and shall be an integer multiple of MinCbSizeY.

but what are luma samples? how to get pixel width from luma samples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to HEVC guide: to save bandwidth in HEVC, width is expressed in multiples of 16; so:

```
videoWidth = ( pic_width_in_luma_sample + 1) * 16;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, that it's wrong.
Thus videoWidth is calculated for h264.

> videoWidth = ( pic_width_in_luma_sample + 1) * 16;

pic_width_in_luma_sample is real video width for HEVC format.